# ManyToMany relations in HQL

Tags: hibernate, hql

I've got the following relations:

```
public class Group {

    private Integer id;
        (...)
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="rb_user_group",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")})
    private List<User> users;
```

and :

```
public class User {

    private int id;
    (...)
    @ManyToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name="rb_user_group",
               joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="user_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="group_id")})
    private List<Group> groups;
}
```

What is the proper way to select all users that belong to some group where group's name is set? 
I tried

```
session.createQuery("SELECT g.user FROM Group g WHERE g.name=:name").setString("name", group.getName());
```

but it doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
session.createQuery("SELECT u FROM User u left join u.groups as g with g = :group").setObject("group", group);
```

Comment: didn't work. It displays all users, no matter of group's name.